# Can't access admin dashboard with Magento 2

Tags: magento, url, path, admin, dashboard

I faced a problem that I changed admin base url from custom admin path to custom admin url and I'm unable to reach admin dashboard - it shows link does not exist.

```
I tried :
-to change values in config_core_data
- set from cli : bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
- search value in app/etc/env.php file
- search for path to admin with :  bin/magento info:adminuri
```

P.S always tried cache:clean,flush and reindex commands.

Some rows from database, maybe someone will catch a mistake:

```
config_id    scope    scope_id          path                    value
3032        default      0         admin/url/custom         admin_ad123/
1776        default      0       admin/url/custom_path      admin_ad123/
1617        default      0        admin/url/use_custom            1
1618        default      0      admin/url/use_custom_path    admin_ad123/
```

It would be awesome if someone could help me out. I think that there is still set admin cutom url and maybe there is possibility to set from cli or mysql to admin custom path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing values in config_core_data table to :

```
1617 default 0 admin/url/use_custom 0
1618 default 0 admin/url/use_custom_path 0
1776 default 0 admin/url/custom_path admin_ad123/
3032 default 0 admin/url/custom
```

Comment: none of the row is present in my table, what should i do?

Comment: the table is core_config_data